# How do I print out this string from within my class?

Tags: c++

I would like to know how to make it so I can print the string variables from my class. I would also like to know if I am using the correct way to to write out my array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ColorPicker {
public:

        string Color[7][10] = { "red" , "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet" };

};

int main()
{
    cout << ColorPicker  << endl;
   system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Find a beginner's book about C++ and flip to the page about classes.

Comment: Or perhaps flip one by one.

Comment: I liked your system("pause")  ....>::))

Comment: Why is array of strings 2 dimensions? You just need 1 dimension.

Comment: ***to know if I am using the correct way to to write out my array*** No it is not correct. Although you did not try to print the array all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `operator-overloading` and `friend function`.

Also you will need to create an object of type `ColorPicker` because `Color` is instance variable.

**Note:** Since `Color` is of `string` type hence, keep it as 1D array.

Following is working code. You can see it working [here](http://ideone.com/862EMy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ColorPicker {
public:

        string Color[7] = { "red" , "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet" };

        friend  ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const ColorPicker& ob)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<7;i++)
            {
                out<< (ob.Color[i])<<" | ";
            }
            return out;
        }

};

int main()
{
    ColorPicker ob;
    cout <<ob<<endl;
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using String then it can be defined as 
string Color[7] = { "red" , "orange","yellow","green","blue", "indigo", "violet"};

Single string is defined as : string c="red" ,in c++.

For printing, you need to make an object for the class like "ColorPicker c" in main.
Make any function for displaying(display) the string in class. 
Call the function display from main via object made for the class.
eg. c.display();